# Is it possible to display chat messages through the Android Paging Library?

Tags: android, android-paging

I want to merge two message list(stored chat message, incoming chat message)

these two data is split based on the last check time.

I want stored chat message to be Paging and merge with incoming data

This is my code:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM msgentity WHERE room_id =:roomId and time <= :lastReadTime ORDER BY time")
fun getPassedMsg(roomId: String, lastReadTime: Date) : PagingSource<Int, MsgEntity>

@Query("SELECT * FROM msgentity WHERE room_id=:roomId and time > :lastReadTime ORDER BY time")
suspend fun getNewMsg(roomId: String, lastReadTime: Date) : Flow<List<MsgEntity>>
```

Is it possible to merge these two items of data?

Or do I have to make my own paging object?

Comment: "is it possible" yes, definitely. However, I think your real question is "how do I?" To answer that question, I suggest you check out RecyclerView.

Comment: is your question how to implement , see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Yeah definitely, you can show messages using paging.
if your question is that how ?
So here I am using MVVM architecture , Kotlin coroutine

> **Step 1.** you need to create a paging source for request and getting response
> (here MessageList is api response model )

```
class MessagePaging(private val apiService: ApiService) : PagingSource<Int, MessageList.Data>() {

    private var STARTING_PAGE_INDEX = 1
    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, MessageList.Data>): Int? {
        return 1
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, MessageList.Data> {
        val page = params.key ?: STARTING_PAGE_INDEX

        return try {
            val response = apiService.getMessageList(page)

            val data = response.body()?.data!!
            if (!data.isNullOrEmpty()){
                LoadResult.Page(
                    data = data,
                    prevKey = if (page == STARTING_PAGE_INDEX) null else page -1,
                    nextKey = if (data.isEmpty()) null else page + 1
                )

            }else{
                return LoadResult.Error(NullPointerException("Data is Null or Empty"))
            }
        } catch (e : HttpException){
            return LoadResult.Error(e)
        } catch (e : IOException){
            return LoadResult.Error(e)
        } catch (e : Exception){
            return LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }

}
```

> **Step 2 :-** Create request in apiservice

```
@GET( GET_CONSULTATION_LIST )
suspend fun getMessageList(@Query("page") page : Int) : Response<MessageList>
```

> **Step 3:-** in ApiHelperImpl interface

```
fun getConsultationList(): Flow<PagingData<ConsultationList.Data>> {
    return Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 40,
            enablePlaceholders = false,
            prefetchDistance = 1
        ),
        pagingSourceFactory = { ConsultantPaging(apiService) }
    ).flow
}
```

> **Step 4 :-** In View model

```
fun getConsultationList() = apiHelper.getConsultationList().cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

> **Step 5 :-** In Fragment

```
    private fun observeConsultations() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.getConsultationList().collectLatest {
                launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    adapter.loadStateFlow.collectLatest { loadStates ->
                        if (loadStates.refresh is LoadState.Loading) {
//                            loader.show()
                        } else {
//                            loader.dismiss()
                            if (loadStates.refresh is LoadState.Error) {
                                if (adapter.itemCount < 1) {
                                    binding.clNoConsult.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                } else {
                                    binding.clNoConsult.visibility = View.GONE
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                adapter.submitData(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

> **Step 6:-** Create Paging Adapter

```
class ConsultationPagingAdapter (private val click: GetClicksOnItem ) : PagingDataAdapter<MessageList.Data, ConsultationPagingAdapter.ViewHolder>(DiffCallback()) {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(ListConsultationsBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val result = getItem(position)!!
        holder.binding.apply {
            tvName.text = result.name.capitalizeWords()
            root.setOnClickListener {
                click.action(result)
            }
            executePendingBindings()
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder(val binding: ListConsultationsBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    private class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<MessageList.Data>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(
            oldItem: MessageList.Data,
            newItem: MessageList.Data
        ): Boolean = oldItem == newItem

        override fun areContentsTheSame(
            oldItem: MessageList.Data,
            newItem: MessageList.Data
        ): Boolean = oldItem == newItem
    }

    interface GetClicksOnItem {
        fun action(data: MessageList.Data)
    }
}
```

If you getting understating then approve the answer